# How to fix AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get' on Discord bot code

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have this function

This function does not working and print
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
How to fix

````
        @self.client.event
        async def on_message(message):
            if message.author == self.client.user:
                return
            if self.check_buttons.get(message.author.id, None):
                ans = None
                for i in range(len(self.check_buttons.get(message.author.id, []))):
                    if self.check_buttons[message.author.id][i].lower() == message.content.lower() or message.content.lower() == "#" + str(i + 1):
                        ans = self.check_buttons[message.author.id][i]
                        break
                if ans:
                    self.channel.send_message(message.author.id, ans)
                    self.check_buttons[message.author.id] = []
                else:
                    msg = "You entered an invalid value. Copy (Short command: # and numbers buttons):\n"
                    for i in range(len(self.btns)):
                        msg += str(i + 1) + ". " + self.btns[i] + "\n"
                    self.send_message(message.author.id, msg)
            else:
                self.channel.send_message(message.author.id,
                                          message.content)  # send event (UserID + UserMessage) to channel```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'something'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/why-do-i-get-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `if ans = self.check_buttons.get(message.author.id, None)` with `if ans = self.check_buttons.get(message.author.id) == None:`